# Changing name of variable each time program is run

Tags: variables, cell-array

I'm trying to create a code that creates objects and stores them in a cell array. I run this:

`assignin('base', 'myVar{i}', myVar{i})`

But I get an error that says "Invalid variable name "myVar{i}" in ASSIGNIN". Can someone please help me figure out how to create these variables with different names and then assign them to a cell array?

Comment: which lang/platform ? this question needs more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fix your error with

```
assignin('base', ['myVar{' num2str(i) '}'], myVar{i})
```

but a solution that doesn't require `assignin` would be much better.  Perhaps a return value?